# Is it possible to combine these two sql statements into one statement using group by?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, count

```sql
select client_type, count(gender) as num_males
from clients
where gender = 'Male'
group by client_type;
```

```sql
select client_type, count(gender) as num_females
from clients
where gender = 'Female'
group by client_type;
```

The following SQL statements show the number of males by client type, then the number of females by client type. I would like an SQL statement to show the following columns: client_type, count(gender = 'Male'), count(gender = 'Female'). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: e.g. `count(iif(gender = 'female', 1, NULL))`

Comment: Some SQL implementations (like MySQL) will allow you to use `COUNT(gender='Male')` type of syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count a couple of `case` expressions:

```sql
SELECT   client_type, 
         COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS num_males,
         COUNT(CASE gender WHEN 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS num_females
FROM     clients
GROUP BY client_type;
```

Comment: I get the following error running your sql statement 'ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @C-W-M-Oliver8012 sorry, forgot the `then` clause in the `case` expressions. I shouldn't;t be answering on SO this late :-( Edited and fixed.